# A question about the definition of regular surfaces in Manfredo do Carmo's book

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question in **Manfredo do Carmo**'s book: **Differential geometry of curves and surfaces**.

According to the explanation of definition of regular surfaces, the condition 2 can avoid some kind of "self-intersection" which are shown with a figure in the book as the following:

[image]

However, at any point except those on the line made by the self-intersection, the surface is locally satisfies the definition of regular surface. At any point $p$ on that line, We can define two different differentiable maps **x**$_1$, **x**$_2$ which can parametrize the two pieces of self-intersection respectively. Because the definition of regular surface allows more than one parametrization **x** for the same point on the surface. It makes we can conclude the above figure is still regular.

Therefore, what kind situation of self-intersection of a surface does the condition 2 want to avoid?

I can't understand it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

One of the hypotheses of Manfredo's definition of regular surface is that there is an open set $U\subset \mathbb R ^ 2$ over the neighborhood $V \cap S \in \mathbb R ^ 3$. To suppose the existence of this open in the problematic line is the absurdity we seek. Remember that for a surface to be regular, it must be regular in all its points. An exercise similar to your counterexample is 10 in section 2.2 of the book.

Comment: What do you mean by "V int S in R ^ 3"?  Can you please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to properly format your mathematics?

Comment: int=intersection. And thank you.