# Does a injective immerse is embedding?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, submanifold

Now I am reading the textbook differential Geometry of curve and Surface by do.carmo. He presents the following proposition:[image]

My question is the regular Surface seems unnecessary in this proof.
The condition 1 and 3 are the same as $X: U\to R^3$ is immerse.

Comment: This is a good question, but it's [already been asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153677/a-question-about-the-definition-of-regular-surfaces-in-manfredo-do-carmos-book?rq=1). Think first about the figure-8 curve and why it's not an embedded smooth curve.